# Can I use MongoDB as a remotely and concurrently accessed server?

Tags: mongodb

Can I use MongoDB as a remotely and concurrently accessed server?
Does it support concurrency out of the box?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It can be remotely hosted and accessed concurrently as any other database. Have a look at the documentation at this link: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/concurrency/